# How to set checked Radio Button on Previous Button in Android?

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm beginner in Android. I have implementing a project which is including question and their answers options with radio button and two buttons next and previous.

1) I have use `xml` parser

2) When i select answers option pressing radio button and click next its appearing next question on the same Activity.

3) When i pressed the previous button it goes to previous question with answers option radio button on the same Activity.

Right now i want to Radio Button Checked in android while i go to previous question on click previous button which i selected. Can Someone help me how to do .Thanks to appreciate.

Here is my code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.questions_screen);

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        databaseHelper.onOpen(sqdb);

        mAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0F, 0.0F);
        mAnimation.setDuration(200L);
        mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
        mAnimation.setRepeatMode(2);


        txtViewQuestiontype = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.QuestionType_TXT);
        txtViewQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Question_TXT);

        Options_RadioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RDOptions);
        AnswerOptionsA_RadioButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RBOption_A);
        AnswerOptionsB_RadioButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RBOption_B);
        AnswerOptionsC_RadioButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RBOption_C);
        AnswerOptionsD_RadioButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RBOption_D);

          button_CheckAnswer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button_Check_Answer_BTN);
          button_Previouse = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button_Previous_BTN);
          button_Next  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button_Next_BTN);
          button_QuestionLimit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn_QuestionLimit);
          button_Home = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHome);

         read_Questions_XML_File();

          button_Previouse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    previousQuestionCalled(v);
                }
            });


            button_Next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    storingResult(); 
                    nextQuestionCalled(v);
                }
            });
    }

    public void storingResult()
    {
        int id = Options_RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        System.out.println("id = " + id);

        if (id > 0)
        {
            AnswerOptions = (RadioButton) findViewById(Options_RadioGroup
                    .getCheckedRadioButtonId());

            String str_AnswerOptions = AnswerOptions.getText().toString()
                    .trim();
            System.out.println("rbVal = " + str_AnswerOptions);

            if (str_AnswerOptions
                    .equals(((Datastructure) Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure
                            .get(StaticClass.QuestionNumber)).Answer))
            {
                // Not StaticClass.isTest = false
                if (!StaticClass.isTest)

                {


                    String str_queNo = button_QuestionLimit.getText()
                            .toString().trim();
                    String strstrqueType = txtViewQuestiontype.getText()
                            .toString().trim();
                    String str_que = txtViewQuestion.getText().toString()
                            .trim();
                    String str_marks = "1";

                    databaseHelper.insertQueDetails(str_queNo, strstrqueType,
                            str_que, str_AnswerOptions, str_marks);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Data Crated Right Succesfully ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if (StaticClass.isTest)
                {
                    StaticClass.resultOfTest = 1 + StaticClass.resultOfTest;
                    ((Datastructure) Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure
                            .elementAt(StaticClass.QuestionNumber))
                            .setResult_Of_Test(true);
                    return;
                }

            }
        }

        else if (id == -1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Select Any Option", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            try 
            {
                if (StaticClass.isTest)
                {
                    ((Datastructure) Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure
                            .elementAt(StaticClass.QuestionNumber))
                            .setResult_Of_Test(false);
                }

                if (!StaticClass.isTest)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                ((Datastructure) Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure
                        .get(StaticClass.QuestionNumber))
                        .setResult_Of_Test(false);

                return;
            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }


    public void nextQuestionCalled(View view)
    {
        //if animationForward == false
        if (animationForward)
        {
            //flag = false
            boolean flag;
            if (animationForward)
            {  flag = false; }

            else { flag = true;}

            animationForward = flag;
        }
        //Return The Number Of Element in this Vector > 0
        //-1 + 1
        if (-1 + Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure.size() > StaticClass.QuestionNumber)
        {
            //If StaticClass.isTest == false
            if (StaticClass.isTest) 
            {
                StaticClass.resultOfTest_Out_OF = 1 + StaticClass.resultOfTest_Out_OF;
                storingResult();
            }
            StaticClass.QuestionNumber = 1 + StaticClass.QuestionNumber;
            reHitting();

            view.clearAnimation();
            if (!StaticClass.isTest) {
                button_QuestionLimit.clearAnimation();
            }

            if (StaticClass.isTest) {
                button_QuestionLimit.clearAnimation();
            }

            return;
        }

        else
        {
            button_QuestionLimit.startAnimation(mAnimation);
            return;
        }
    }






    public void syoutF()
    {
        addVallues();
    }

    public void previousQuestionCalled(View view)
    {
        if (!animationForward)
        {
            boolean flag;

            if (animationForward) 
            {
                flag = false;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = true;
            }
            animationForward = flag;
        }
        if (StaticClass.QuestionNumber > 0)
        {
            if (!StaticClass.isTest)
            {
                StaticClass.QuestionNumber = -1 + StaticClass.QuestionNumber;
                reHitting();
                button_QuestionLimit.clearAnimation();
            }
            view.clearAnimation();

        } 
        else 
        {
            button_QuestionLimit.startAnimation(mAnimation);
        }

    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void reHitting() {
        addVallues();
        if (!animationForward)
        {
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_in,R.anim.anim_out);
            return;
        } 
        else 
        {
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_in,R.anim.anim_out);
            return;
        }
    }

    public void addVallues() {
        try {
            txtViewQuestiontype.setText(((Datastructure) Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure
                    .get(StaticClass.QuestionNumber)).Question_Type);

            txtViewQuestion.setText(((Datastructure) Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure
                    .get(StaticClass.QuestionNumber)).Question);

            AnswerOptionsA_RadioButton.setText(((Datastructure) Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure
                    .get(StaticClass.QuestionNumber)).OptionA);

            AnswerOptionsB_RadioButton.setText(((Datastructure) Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure
                    .get(StaticClass.QuestionNumber)).OptionB);

            AnswerOptionsC_RadioButton.setText(((Datastructure) Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure
                    .get(StaticClass.QuestionNumber)).OptionC);

            AnswerOptionsD_RadioButton.setText(((Datastructure) Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure
                    .get(StaticClass.QuestionNumber)).OptionD);
            QuestionLimitFetcher();
            Options_RadioGroup.clearCheck();
            return;
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException arrayindexoutofboundsexception) {
            arrayindexoutofboundsexception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void QuestionLimitFetcher() {
        int i = Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure.size();
        button_QuestionLimit.setText((new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(1 + StaticClass.QuestionNumber)))
                                                               .append("/").append(i).toString());

        String strLimit = button_QuestionLimit.getText().toString().trim();
        System.out.println("strLimit = " + strLimit);
    }



    public void read_Questions_XML_File()
    {

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String string_Chapter_Title = extras.getString("TOPIC_TITLE");
        System.out.println("value1 = " + string_Chapter_Title);

        try
            {
                if (string_Chapter_Title.equals("OOPs concepts"))
                {
                    String encodedXML = URLEncoder.encode("collections.xml");
                    db = SAXXMLParser.parse(getAssets().open(encodedXML));
                    i = Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure.size();
                    System.out.println("Vector Size i" + i);

                    int lastIndex = Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure.lastIndexOf(db.lastElement());
                    System.out.println("lastIndex = " + lastIndex);



                }

                else if (string_Chapter_Title.equals("Java virtual machine"))
                {
                    String encodedXML = URLEncoder.encode("java_keyword.xml");
                    db = SAXXMLParser.parse(getAssets().open(encodedXML));
                    i = Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure.size();
                    System.out.println("Vector Size i" + i);

                    System.out.println("Last element: " + (Integer)Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure.lastElement()); 
                }

            } 
            catch (IOException ioexception)
            {
                ioexception.printStackTrace();
            } 

            catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            syoutF();
        }

    }
```

Comment: radioButton.setChecked(true);

Comment: radio button is in unchecked state when you go to previous question?

Comment: @bean_droid :- Yes , I want to show the previous radio button was selected on previous button .

Comment: @Spark : yah, but i don't understand how to checked state when pressed on previous button . Because i have 4 radio button in Radio group.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the marked answer in shared Preferences against question number,means make Question number or any other valid unique key related to question as key for shared Preferences

like

```
editor.put("Q1",1);  // editor.put(QuestionNo, AnswerNumber);
```

Now when you move back first check if this question has key in shared Preferences, if yes the check the radiobutton according to the answerNumber saved .